# React Native: inject different implementation depending on the build type

Tags: react-native

There are multiple build types: *dev*, *acc*, *prod*, *mock* for the app. And for a certain build type, I want to inject different implementation of some functions.

### For example:

**In non-mock build types**

```
export const login = (uname, pswd) => service_login(uname, pswd);
login("foo", "bar");
```

**In mock build type**

```
export const login = (uname, pswd) => true;
login("foo", "bar");
```

Coming from Android development, it's possible to use different source sets for different build types in Gradle.

In React Native, how do we organize the source code or setup the project to enable this functionality?

**Expected solution criteria:**

- Avoid bundling unnecessary source sets in the final build (i.e: production build should not contain debug / mock codes).
- No if else all over the place.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a global **DEV** variable in all your modules which will be set to true in case of dev builds.

```
if(__DEV__) {
  // do dev stuff
} else {
  // shit's getting real
}
```

Comment: __DEV__ is only for debug build type. And using if else all over the place is really not elegant / clean solution.

Comment: You should mention that in your question.

Comment: Well, "mock" is not debug build type from React Native perspective. And solution has to be elegant in any case.